# OData Automapper RAM-Usage on ProjectTo and [EnableQuery]

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, odata, automapper

The following code is used to pass an IQueryable to OData and then apply the filter.

The data is loaded from the database and converted to a Dto by Automapper.

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Notes.ProjectTo<NoteDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider));
    }
```

Via [EnableQuery] the filter is applied to the return of IQueryable. The question I have now is, if I use ProjectTo before the filter, will all the data without the filter be read first? In case of millions of records this would only use memory unnecessarily.

If I am correct in my assumption, how can I prevent this?

I have tried the following code:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<NoteDto> Get()
    {
        return _db.Notes.UseAsDataSource(mapper.ConfigurationProvider).For<NoteDto>();
    }
```

But here $expand doesn't work anymore and if the memory usage is lower I can't really judge either

Comment: *will all the data without the filter be read first* - no. `ProjectTo` generates gust `Queryable.Select`, which is part of the normal query.